How to compile f90 files using Brew?
I downloaded Brew, and downloaded GCC from it. I didn't know what file to use, so I went with a text editor file that I renamed FortranTest.f90
Ran it in the compiler and and got this error:
1 | {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2759
      |  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:2:2:

    2 | \cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
      |  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:2:74:

    2 | \cocoatextscaling0\cocoaplatform0{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
      |                                                                          1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:3:2:

    3 | {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
      |  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:3:13:

    3 | {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
      |             1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:3:37:

    3 | {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
      |                                     1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:4:2:

    4 | {\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
      |  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:4:23:

    4 | {\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
      |                       1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:5:2:

    5 | \margl1440\margr1440\vieww11520\viewh8400\viewkind0
      |  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:6:2:

    6 | \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0
      |  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:8:2:

    8 | \f0\fs24 \cf0 program f90_Test\
      |  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:9:1:

    9 | \
      | 1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:11:1:

   11 | \
      | 1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:12:14:

   12 | print *, TEXT\
      |              1
Error: Syntax error in PRINT statement at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:13:1:

   13 | \
      | 1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
/Users/BLANK/Desktop/FortranTest.f90:14:21:

   14 | end program f90_Test}
      |                     1
Error: Syntax error in END PROGRAM statement at (1)

The EXACT error (I copied it) please help! Tell me if I did it wrong!
The file contents were:
program f90_Test

char TEXT = "HELLO WORLD"

print *, TEXT

end program f90_Test


You have saved your file as a .rtf document, then renamed it to .f90. This means, your compiler received gibberish instead of Fortran code. You have to save it as plain text in the first place, or use some conversion tool. Rich Text (.rtf) documents contain formatting instructions that tell your editor which fonts you want to use, where to bold, etc... and it is not something a Fortran compiler can understand.
To that end — TextEdit is a very bad choice for a code editor. Popular choices on Mac are nano, vim, emacs, Visual Studio Code, TextMate, Sublime Text, and more. Your Mac comes with nano and vim preinstalled. nano compared to vim is like a tricycle compared to a space shuttle: both get you places, but one is much more powerful — and complicated — than the other.

Thanks! I really appreciate the help! Also, how do you access nano?

In terminal, type nano FortranTest.f90.

The second line in your code is meaningless in Fortran. The type char does not exist in Fortran, but the equivalent to it is character:
character(*), parameter :: text = "HELLO WORLD"
print *, text
end

The * appears in place of the length type parameter of the character type and means infer the length of text as a parameter (constant) from its value.If you drop the * it will only assign the first character to text because text is assumed to be a character of length 1 by default.
character, parameter :: text = "HELLO WORLD"
print *, text
end

In general, you probably want an allocatable instead of a constant. So, the following would be more flexible:
character(:), allocatable :: text
text = "HELLO WORLD"
print *, text
text = "I am a Fortran entousiast!"
print *, text
end

The : implies the string has deferred length and must be set at runtime. Notice I removed program and end program from your original code because they are optional. The smallest valid Fortran program is:
end

See the output of each code snippet by pasting it in https://godbolt.org/.
